# Focus em campo inválido jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando a biblioteca jQuery Validate para fazer algumas validações em um formulário e gostaria de sabe se alguém sabe como poderia fazer o foco ficar sempre no campo, no caso de ele ser inválido. Atualmente, ele sai do campo inválido mas não deixa submeter até ser corrigido. Segue código:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {

 $("#cadastro").validate({
  // Define as regras, pega sempre pela ID. Se não passar (caso do combo) usa o Name.
  rules:{
   cracha:{
    // ordem será obrigatório (required), numérico e terá tamanho mínimo (minLength)
    required: true, number: true,  minlength: 4
   }
  },
  // Define as mensagens de erro para cada regra
  messages:{
   cracha:{
    required: "Passe o crachá! ",
    number: "Somente numeros!",
     minlength: "Minimo 4 digitos!"
   }
  }
 });
});
```

Alguma idéia?

Comment: Já deveria funcionar por _default_. Tenta por a opção `focusInvalid: true`

Comment: Deu certo....Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O focus nos campos inválidos já deveria estar ativado por *default*. Mas você pode forçar a ativação setando nas opções, assim:

```
focusInvalid: true
```

Para mais informações veja a documentação do *plugin*: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate